# scss variables not working in Angular Bootstrap Charts

Tags: css, angular, scss-lint

How can i using scss variable in Angular Bootstrap charts? I tried the following

```
this.chartvpColors = [
      {
        backgroundColor: "var(--barchartClr)" ,
        borderColor: "var(--barchartborderClr)",
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 137, 132, .2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 10, 130, .7)',
        borderWidth: 2,
      }
    ];

<canvas mdbChart [chartType]="chartvpType" [datasets]="chartvpDatasets" [labels]="chartvpLabels" [colors]="chartvpColors"[options]="chartvpOptions" [legend]="true" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

But the scss variable is not working